# Erase Swing Content Pane/Panel & display a new panel

Tags: java, swing

I have created an applet where when you press the button "Forgot Pass" I erase the current JPanel on the applet & create a new JPanel that displays the JComponents related to Retrieving/Forgetting a password.

*I can successfully clear the JPanel using .removeAll(); **BUT** after I create all my new JComponents & add them to the content pane (main JPanel) the applet just goes gray & doesn't show the new JPanel & components **UNLESS** I resize the applet, then it repaints & works.*

I have tried putting .invalidate() after I have created all the new JComponents but that still doesn't refresh the applet?

**How can I make my JPanel appear after I clear it with .removeAll() & add different JComponents to it?**

Code:

```
public class App extends JApplet
{
    JPanel mainPanel; 

    public void init()
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                showLoginPanel(); // this shows fine on loading
            }
        });

    }

    public void showForgotPassPanel()
    {
        mainPanel.removeAll();

        mainPanel = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        Box hBox  = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        Box vBox  = Box.createVerticalBox();
        mainPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); 

        ... create components

        ... add components to mainPanel

        mainPanel.invalidate(); // doesn't make new layout visible, not unless I resize the applet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `mainPanel.revalidate();` and/or `mainPanel.repaint();` methods.

Comment: Using JRE7, I was required to use both. A simple repaint left me with an empty gray pane, and a simple revalidate drew the new contents over the old.

Answer (score 0):

Another "clean" option is to swap views with a CardLayout.  It does all the dirty work for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;

public class PruebaVentana extends JFrame {
    JButton b1, b2;
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel contenedor = new JPanel();

    public PruebaVentana() throws HeadlessException, InterruptedException {
        super("Abriendo nuevo JPanel por medio de un botón");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 300);

        iniciarPanel();
    }// fin de constructor PruebaVentana

    public void iniciarPanel() {
        this.getContentPane().add(contenedor);
        contenedor.setLayout(null);
        contenedor.add(this.panel1);
        contenedor.add(this.panel2);
        panel2.setBackground(new Color(0, 10, 150));
        panel1.setBackground(new Color(150, 0, 0));

        panel1.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 230);
        panel2.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 230);
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel2.setLayout(null);
        panel2.setVisible(false);

        b1 = new JButton("Abre Panel 2");
        b2 = new JButton("Abre Panel 1");

        b1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30);
        b1.setForeground(new Color(200, 100, 50));
        b2.setBounds(170, 10, 150, 30);
        b2.setForeground(new Color(50, 100, 200));

        panel1.add(b1);
        panel2.add(b2);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel2.setVisible(true);
                panel1.setVisible(false);
            }// fin de actionPerformed
        });// fin de actionListener

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel1.setVisible(true);
                panel2.setVisible(false);
            }// fin de actionPerformed
        });// fin de actionListener

    }// fin de iniciarPanel

    public static void main(String[] args) throws HeadlessException, InterruptedException {
        PruebaVentana v = new PruebaVentana();
        v.setVisible(true);

    }// fin de método main

}// fin de clase PruebaVentana
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.